# How to select_related() in Flask/SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Having following models:

```
 class Question(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
   title = db.Column(db.String(125))
   text = db.Column(db.Text())
   answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='for_question')


class Answer(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  text = db.Column(db.Text())
  question_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('question.id'))
```

How can I perform select_related in SQLAlchemy/Flask?

I've found in documentation that I can  make something like

`session.query(Question).options(joinedload(Question.aswers))`

But I need first to get specific question by id and then select related to it

So I need something like this

```
Question.query.get(5).select_related()
```

Ho can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
answers = Question.query.options(joinedload(Question.answers)).get(5).answers
```

The expression `Question.query.options(joinedload(Question.answers)).get(5)` issues the query with a join and evaluates to a `Question` instance. Accessing `answers` attribute does not issue any queries.

You could also do it more explicitly

```
answers = Answer.query.filter_by(question_id=5).all()
```

Comment: Explicit version assumes you don't want the Question of the Answer. `joinedload` is the way to go here.