# Slow for loop in python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

I have an api which is supposed to get me the venue details from a set of events. There are around 10000 events and the whole process to generate the list is taking around 6.5 seconds because of which the server cpu usage shoots up to 100% and loading of the page is slow. I am using mongodb. Here is the function:

```
def get_venue():
events_all = Event.objects.all()
locality = ""
venue = []
data = ({'success':False, 'venue': venue})
for event in events_all:
    venue_json = {'venue_name':"", 'local':"", 'locat_id':""}
    try:
        try:
            venue_json['venue_name'] = event.location.location_name
        except Exception as e:
            venue_json['venue_name'] = ""
        try:
            venue_json['local'] = event.location.parent.location_name
        except Exception as e:
            venue_json['local'] = ""
        venue_json['locat_id'] = event.location.location_id
        venue.append(venue_json)
    except Exception as e:
        continue
if len(venue) > 0:
    data['success'] = True
return json.dumps(data)
```

If I remove the loop then the page loads in under a second. Is there any way to optimize this and bring down the loop time to minimal?

Comment: The main way would be to limit the amount of events you're parsing. Just use a slice like `for event in events_all[:100]` to only the first 100 events. You could alter the number or whether it's the events at the start or end of the list. Apart from that, you're initialising all the values as empty at the start of the loop, but they all get set after that anyway. You may as well initialise an empty dictionary to save a bit of time.

Comment: I have to parse all the events at once because all of the events hold a venue details.  And i have to display all the venues as dropdown in select tag. The only problem is that it is taking too much time to go over all the events. Any other suggestions?

Comment: do all `event` items have `location` as attributes, and do all `location` items have `parent` as attributes?

Comment: Well some event has and some not. So, instead of hitting db to check whether that attribute exist or not,  i chose to use try except block. As i thot hitting to db will slow it further down..

Comment: difficult to say without being sure exactly what your data looks like, but at the very least, bringing `venue_json['locat_id'] = event.location.location_id` to be immediately beneath your first `try` is likely to bring the running time down somewhat.

Comment: @zehnpaard will try and post here and also will post the type of data i am accessing.

Comment: I think, the main point is that the actual database query only is executed (Django is lazy that way) when you iterate over the QuerySet `events_all`. Without the loop, there is no database query at all.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I am using flask. But yeah i agree on that point that actual query set is executed when we use that events_all. Other wise the object would be in a local variable and it would have executed much faster

Answer (score 1):

With `select_related` you can avoid extra database lookups in the for loop (see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
events_all = Event.objects.all().select_related('location__parent')
```

Comment: I am using flask. Is it supported in flask also?

Comment: Idk, this is Django syntax, but there should to be similar functionality in flask:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983129/how-to-select-related-in-flask-sqlalchemy